# What is the method for calculating the standard deviation of a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just starting out with a statistics class that requires us to use Python for most problems.

I keep getting this error and I'm stuck on working through it. I had a similar code prior to that was `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'variance'` and I solved that with using `var()`.

Now I need to get the standard deviation and tried to use `stdev()`, but I get an error

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stdev'

What is the correct method I should use?

```
print("Your Team's Relative Skill in 2013 to 2015")
print("-------------------------------------------------------")

# ---- TODO: make your edits here ----
mean = your_team_df['elo_n'].mean()
median = your_team_df['elo_n'].median()
variance = your_team_df['elo_n'].var()
stdeviation = your_team_df['elo_n'].stdev()

print('Mean =', round(mean,2))
print('Median =', round(median,2))
print('Variance =', round(variance,2))
print('Standard Deviation =', round(stdeviation,2))
```

```
 Your Team's Relative Skill in 2013 to 2015
-------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-fbe446dfb1af> in <module>
      6 median = your_team_df['elo_n'].median()
      7 variance = your_team_df['elo_n'].var()
----> 8 stdeviation = your_team_df['elo_n'].stdev()
      9 
     10 print('Mean =', round(mean,2))

~/anaconda3/envs/codio/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5178             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5179                 return self[name]
-> 5180             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5181 
   5182     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stdev'
```

Answer (score 2):

`pandas.Series` does not have a method called `stdev`. If you are looking for standard deviation, use the method `std`

```
stdeviation = your_team_df['elo_n'].std()
```